# ID Token using facebook login

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-oauth

I'm trying to get a JWT id token from sign-in with Facebook, but it only seems to want to return an OAuth access token. I have been able to get all the user information, but I want an OIDC Compliant ID token, which I can't seem to get. [Limited Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/limited-login/) seems to get this done, but it doesn't look like it's available for web use.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score -1):

Add the `openid` scope to the Facebook OAuth scopes. Then you will get IdToken.